# Background image on DIV with percentage

Tags: css, background-image, percentage

I´m trying to learn about DIVs with percentage sizes and background-image.
So...

```
.mydiv
{
float: left;
width: 20%;
background-image: url('myimage.png');
padding-bottom: 20%;
background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;  /* Firefox 3.6 */
background-position: center;  /* Internet Explorer 7/8 */
}
```

The view is not soooo bad. Anyway, I´d like to improve it, for a responsive site.

**myimage.png >> 1920 x 964**

I searched and found some tutorials. But... I´m stuck.
I don´t want to use javascript to manage the resize. **I´m trying to find the BEST way to do it with CSS, mostly, to learn and improve the view of the image as background**

Anyone can help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

for responsive background set `width:100%`

example:

```
.mydiv
{
float: left;
width: 100%;
background-image: url('http://bestinspired.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/4-Nature-Wallpapers-2014-1.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;
background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;  /* Firefox 3.6 */
background-position: center;  /* Internet Explorer 7/8 */
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h9hmu2Lu/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes... But still the problem between WIDTH and HEIGHT proportion.
I´m using now a padding-bottom of 100%, so I´ve a "square div". Is not another way to improve the view of the background-image? Thanks again! Im trying to learn :D